# Retrieve entire row with ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Is it possible to retrieve  entire row without calling getInt(..) getString(..) for every column?

I have multiple threads, each tread needs to write the result to some thread safe collection.
I want to be able to write the rows directly to this collection, and after that parse the members of this collection and retrieve the values based on column types.

Comment: No. You need to parse the row into `Objects` and store those in the `Collection`. Consider _querying_ the data in chunks in threads.

Comment: If you don't want to write such code, have a look at e.g. Spring JDBC template. It reliefs you of a lot of such boiler plate code without the burden of an ORM.

Comment: You want an ORM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+orm?sort=frequent&pagesize=50 or google for java orm

Answer (score 12):

You can build a class like this one, which maps sql data types with java data types:

```
class Row
{
    public Map <Object,Class> row;
    public static Map <String, Class> TYPE;

    static
    {
        TYPE = new HashMap<String, Class>();

        TYPE.put("INTEGER", Integer.class);
        TYPE.put("TINYINT", Byte.class);
        TYPE.put("SMALLINT", Short.class);
        TYPE.put("BIGINT", Long.class);
        TYPE.put("REAL", Float.class);
        TYPE.put("FLOAT", Double.class);
        TYPE.put("DOUBLE", Double.class);
        TYPE.put("DECIMAL", BigDecimal.class);
        TYPE.put("NUMERIC", BigDecimal.class);
        TYPE.put("BOOLEAN", Boolean.class);
        TYPE.put("CHAR", String.class);
        TYPE.put("VARCHAR", String.class);
        TYPE.put("LONGVARCHAR", String.class);
        TYPE.put("DATE", Date.class);
        TYPE.put("TIME", Time.class);
        TYPE.put("TIMESTAMP", Timestamp.class);
        // ...
    }
    
    public Row ()
    {
        row = new HashMap<Object,Class>();
    }
    
    public <T> void add (T data)
    {
        row.put(data, data.getClass());
    }

    public void add (Object data, String sqlType)
    {
        add((Row.TYPE.get(sqlType)) data);
    }

    public static void formTable (ResultSet rs, ArrayList<Row> table)
    {
        if (rs == null) return;
    
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    
        int NumOfCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    
        while (rs.next())
        {
            row = new Row ();
        
            for(int i = 1; i <= NumOfCol; i++)
            {
                row.add(rs.getObject(i), rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
            }

            table.add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can use it like this:

```
List<Row> table = new ArrayList<Row>();

Row row = null;

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name");

Row.formTable(rs, table);
```

Then you can retrieve fields and cast them to their respective data types:

```
for (Row row : table)
{

    for (Object data : row.row.getKeySet())
    {
        System.out.print(" > " + ((row.row.get(data) data));
    }
    
    System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, good piece of code. One comment: I think that a single row should not be represented as a Map, but as a List because the columns are ordered in a table. Thus, I'd change the Row's row to something like that: public List<Entry<Object, Class>> row; There is not enough space here so I pasted my code in a new entry below.

Answer (score 6):

Row represented as a list:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * @author Adam Dziedzic
 * 
 */
public class Row {
    public List<Entry<Object, Class>> row;
    public static Map<String, Class> TYPE;

    static {
        TYPE = new HashMap<String, Class>();

        TYPE.put("INTEGER", Integer.class);
        TYPE.put("TINYINT", Byte.class);
        TYPE.put("SMALLINT", Short.class);
        TYPE.put("BIGINT", Long.class);
        TYPE.put("REAL", Float.class);
        TYPE.put("FLOAT", Double.class);
        TYPE.put("DOUBLE", Double.class);
        TYPE.put("DECIMAL", BigDecimal.class);
        TYPE.put("NUMERIC", BigDecimal.class);
        TYPE.put("BOOLEAN", Boolean.class);
        TYPE.put("CHAR", String.class);
        TYPE.put("VARCHAR", String.class);
        TYPE.put("LONGVARCHAR", String.class);
        TYPE.put("DATE", Date.class);
        TYPE.put("TIME", Time.class);
        TYPE.put("TIMESTAMP", Timestamp.class);
        TYPE.put("SERIAL",Integer.class);
        // ...
    }

    public Row() {
        row = new ArrayList<Entry<Object, Class>>();
    }

    public <T> void add(T data) {
        row.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Object,Class>(data, data.getClass()));
    }

    public void add(Object data, String sqlType) {
        Class castType = Row.TYPE.get(sqlType.toUpperCase());
        try {
            this.add(castType.cast(data));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Row.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage()+" Add the type "+sqlType+" to the TYPE hash map in the Row class.", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static void formTable(ResultSet rs, List<Row> table)
            throws SQLException {
        if (rs == null)
            return;

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
        try {
            rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            int NumOfCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Row current_row = new Row();

                for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfCol; i++) {
                    current_row.add(rs.getObject(i), rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
                }

                table.add(current_row);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Row> table = new ArrayList<Row>();

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name");

Row.formTable(rs, table);

for (Row row : table)
{
    for (Entry<Object, Class> col: row.row)
    {
        System.out.print(" > " + ((col.getValue()).cast(col.getKey())));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: *TYPE.put("INTEGER", Integer.class);* could be changed to *TYPE.put("INT", Integer.class);*

Comment: *TYPE.put("INTEGER", Integer.class);* could be changed to *TYPE.put("INT", Integer.class);*

Comment: the OP specifically asked for a solution that does NOT iterate through the columns

Comment: It would be better to catch the SQL exception and to log it instead of just catching the exception and throwing it back to the caller.

Comment: Probably it'd be better to skip this try / catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a query to work out the size of the query and then splitting up the processing to multiple threads.

I use MySQL, so the queries are written for that. You'll need to change the queries for you database engine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int count;
    try (final Connection conn = DATA_SOURCE.getConnection()) {
        final String countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table";
        try (final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(countQuery);
                final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery()) {
            resultSet.next();
            count = resultSet.getInt(1);
        }
    }
    final int chunksize = 1000;
    final Queue<SqlResult> results = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for (int end = 0; end < count; end += chunksize) {
        es.execute(new ResultReader(count, end, DATA_SOURCE, results));
    }
}

private static class ResultReader implements Runnable {

    private final int start;
    private final int size;
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final Queue<SqlResult> results;

    public ResultReader(int start, int size, DataSource dataSource, Queue<SqlResult> results) {
        this.start = start;
        this.size = size;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            final String query = "SELECT id, something, somethingElse FROM my_table LIMIT ?, ?";
            try (final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
                ps.setInt(1, start);
                ps.setInt(2, size);
                try (final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        final SqlResult sqlResult = new SqlResult();
                        sqlResult.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                        sqlResult.setSomething(rs.getString("something"));
                        sqlResult.setSomethingElse(rs.getString("somethingElse"));
                        results.add(sqlResult);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

private static class SqlResult {

    private int id;
    private String something;
    private String somethingElse;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public String getSomethingElse() {
        return somethingElse;
    }

    public void setSomethingElse(String somethingElse) {
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }
}
```

This assumes that you already have connection pooling, using a `DataSource`.

Each of the workers, runs a query using `LIMIT` and processes the results into `SqlResult` objects and adds them to a concurrent `Queue`.

Comment: Is not `LIMIT ?, ?` a MySQL reserved keywork? AFAIK it won't work on Oracle nor SQL Server.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza fair point. I don't know of a generic way to do this. I will amend my answer to mention that it is MySQL specific.

Comment: thanks, but my "issue" is with resultSet.getInt(1) I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: p.s. I am not using a connection pool (don't think I need it) I am creating 4 connection for 4 theeads.

Answer (score 0):

I used adam.cajf answer, very useful, however, I needed to add one line of code to add function, otherwise it was throwing an error in my particular data set.

```
if (data != null) {
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding the relevant code for the referenced answer, or simply post your feedback as a comment on the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

No.

According to the Java documentation, there is no method that allows you to retrieve the results without specifying the column label or index.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html